# How to create this very complex MySQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, concatenation

I have a serious troubles with creating the proper query for the following:

- I have 3 tables.

1. **authors** ( author_id(int), author_name(varchar) ),
2. **books** ( book_id(int), book_title(varchar) )
3. **contribution** ( book_id(int), author_id(int), prec(double)) -- for storing the precentage how deeply an author is involved in creation of a specific book. (so one book may have more then one author)

And the legendary difficulty (for me right now) query has to ask database for book_id, book_title and in a third column all authors of the specified book concatenated with comma and ordered by perecentage of participation. So I have as many rows in the result of the query as many books I have in the books table, and to every book I have to get the title, and authors in a third column. But how can be such mysql query forged?

Comment: Try to format your text better. Also add sample table data and the expected result, and your current query attempt.

Comment: [Group_Concat()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) lets you combine multiple rows into one based on grouping and sort results by something...  percent perhaps for your query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Little vague on the 3rd table (name) and the join criteria but this should be close...

The key here is the function group_Concat() which allows you to combine multiple rows into one based on the group by values.  Additionally the group_Concat function allows you to define a deliminator as well as an order by.

```
SELECT B.Book_ID
     , B.Book_Title
     , group_concat(A.Author_name order by ABP.Prec Desc separator ', ') as Authors
FROM Author_Book_Percent ABP
INNER JOIN AUTHORS A
  on ABP.Author_ID = A.Author_ID
INNER JOIN BOOKS B
  on ABP.Book_ID = B.Book_ID
GROUP BY B.Book_ID, B.Book_Title
```

Comment: Impossibly easy..same on me, I should have made it! :) Thy for your kindness!

Comment: Easy yes, but only if you know about the Group_Concat() function!

Comment: I knew this function, but only in general...I did not know I could use such order. Thy once more!